# Orange canvas: does not give the polynomal regression coefficients

Tags: canvas, regression, logistic-regression, orange, coefficients

I am using the Orange canvas to handle a caotic data set. I want to get a regression equation, I am using univariate polynomial regression tool and it gives the related graphs but it does not give any equation or coefficient about it. Is there any way, widget tool or code to import this feature in Orange. Thank you all already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect the data into the [*Rank* widget](http://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/visual-programming/widgets/data/rank.html). Univariate LR is one of the feature scorers for regression data.

Answer (score 3):

'Logistic Regression', 'Linear Regression', 'Univariate Polynomial Regression' (and possibly other) widgets output a 'Coefficients' data table.
[image]

Comment: Where can I see the coefficients inside Univariate Polynomial Regression tool ? Inside the widget, at the left side I can get the section which I can change variables and  the right side graph of them. So I can not understand where the coefficients are.

Comment: You have to a new "Data Table" widget into the workflow and connect it to the "Univariate Polynomial Regression" (I added a screen shot to clarify)

Comment: Thank you so so much for your helps and interest. It was perfect that you shared with me the screenshot. Last question I want to ask, when I change the polynomial expansion value, the number of coefficients are increasing. So, I am confused about how I write the right equation. So, May I ask for an example equation from you according to the value of screenshot ?